# Swift 3: Instance Member cannot be used on type “View Controller”

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, uiimageview

I'm trying to update a `UIimageview` image with a method inside a class with a `viewDidLoad()` call. I'm trying to change the image by:

```
MyIMage.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
```

but its giving me the error of:

```
Instance member cannot be used on type "view controller"
```

Where am I going wrong?

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var MyImage: UIImageView!

    var MyStruct = ChangeImage()

    struct ChangeImage {

        private var _isChanged: Bool = false

        mutating func Set_Change(val: Bool) {

            if (val) {
                MyImage.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
                self._isChanged = true
            } else {
                MyImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
                self.isChanged = false
            }
        }

        func isChanged()-> Bool {
            return self._isChanged
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        MyStruct.Set_Change(val: true)
        print (MyStruct.isChanged())
    }

}
```

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you don't understand the difference between a class and an object (which is an instance of a class). You are attempting to use MyImage, which is a class, as if it was an object. You would be advised to read basic books or tutorials on object oriented programming before going further so you understand the fundamentals as you won't get anywhere if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that works :

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

`@IBOutlet var MyImage: UIImageView!  // Insert Outlet Image : "MyImage"

// Structure ChangeImage
struct ChangeImage {
    private var _isChanged: Bool = false
    private var _myImage: UIImageView!   // Private variable _myImage

    init (ImgView: UIImageView) {        // Initiate ImgView called since func viewDidLoad()
        self._myImage = ImgView          // Private variable _myImage = ImgView ( variable MyImage in func viewDidLoad() )
    }

    mutating func Set_Change(val: Bool) {

        if (val) {
            _myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
            self._isChanged = true
        } else {
            _myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
            self._isChanged = false
        }
    }

    func isChanged()-> Bool {
        return self._isChanged
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var MyStruct = ChangeImage(ImgView: MyImage) // Initiate Structure ChangeImage with variable MyImage.
    MyStruct.Set_Change(val: true)
    print (MyStruct.isChanged())
}`

}

;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the structure can't use the variable from the `ViewController` class, so I changed it to a function that does the same thing:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!

    func Set_Change(val: Bool) -> Bool {

        if (val) {
            myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
            return true
        } else {
            myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
            return false
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let didChange = Set_Change(val: true)
        print(didChange)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting this code, but I have always an error again in the line "let myImage = MyImage ()" : Instance member ‘MyImage’ cannot be used on type ‘ViewController’

Comment: @Dominique What are the contents of your MyImage class?

Comment: @IBOutlet var MyImage: UIImageView!

Comment: @Dominique Oh I see! Sorry, I thought that the MyImage was a class - my bad. I'll try to get back to you with an answer soon!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I wanted to use the structures in this code.
For my part I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extract of the code corrected but with the same error in line : let _myImage = MyImage()

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var MyImage: UIImageView!

var MyStruct = ChangeImage()

struct ChangeImage {
    private var _isChanged: Bool = false
    let _myImage = MyImage()  // ----> Error : Instance member ‘MyImage’ cannot be used on type ‘ViewController’
    mutating func Set_Change(val: Bool) {

        if (val) {
            _myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
            self._isChanged = true
        } else {
            _myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
            self._isChanged = false
        }
    }

    func isChanged()-> Bool {
        return self._isChanged
    }
}
```